# Oracle Stored Proc Varchar 3 character limitation

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

This is my stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "YOUQI_SP"
(
    INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2,
    INPUT2 IN VARCHAR2,
    OUTPUT1 OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
    OUTPUT1 := INPUT1 || INPUT2;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INPUT1 : ' || INPUT1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INPUT2 : ' || INPUT2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUTPUT1 : ' || OUTPUT1);
END YOUQI_SP;
```

There's no problem executing: `BEGIN YOUQI_SP('a', 'bc', :output1); END;`. Here's the result:

```
Array
(
    [output1] => abc
)
Array
(
    [0] => INPUT1 : a
    [1] => INPUT2 : bc
    [2] => OUTPUT1 : abc
)
```

But if I add one more character to the input, I will receive the error:

```
[code] => 6502
[message] => ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at "YOUQI_SP", line 9 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

This further proven by assigning variable directly to `OUTPUT1`. It can only hold a maximum of 3 characters. Any idea how can I make it return more than 3 characters? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the complete code that you're using to call the procedure, and identify the environment that you're calling it from.

Comment: OUT parameters are variables decalred in the calling i.e. client environment.  So the error lies there and not in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your output variable is too short. Consider:

```
SQL> var output1 varchar2(2)
SQL> BEGIN YOUQI_SP('aXXX', 'bcXXXX', :output1); END;
  2  /
BEGIN YOUQI_SP('aXXX', 'bcXXXX', :output1); END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "TEST1.YOUQI_SP", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> var output1 varchar2(30)
SQL> BEGIN YOUQI_SP('aXXX', 'bcXXXX', :output1); END;
  2  /
INPUT1 : aXXX
INPUT2 : bcXXXX
OUTPUT1 : aXXXbcXXXX
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.